# D3 adding interval on X axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

Trying to get intervals on the X axis. The X axis should display the 1st of every month(1st Jan, 1st Feb, etc). Also looking at how to zoom in the chart to show the days (1-31 Jan). So far i've got a brush only to work as i'm still new to creating bar charts in D3.

```
var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(x)
    .on('brush', bListener);

var gBrush = svg.select('g.brush').call(brush);

gBrush.selectAll('rect')
        .attr('height', height - margin.top - margin.bottom)
        .style("opacity", 0.5)
        .style("fill", ""grey");
```

Looking to create something like this but as a bar chart in D3,  http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series.

Here's https://jsfiddle.net/noobiecode/wck4ur9d/4/

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer:

How to display the 1st of every month(1st Jan, 1st Feb, etc):

In your xAxis instead of this:

```
   .ticks(d3.time.days, 1)
```

do this:

```
.ticks(d3.time.months)
```

working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/stjd1akj/)

Regarding brushing i didn't see any examples, may be you need to write it on your own :(